# Transparency in shader opengles2

Tags: opengl-es

I have the following shader with two passes and scene blend but I see those faces marked in black..

how would I maintain transparency and not see these faces in the picture ?

The material does two passes on cull faces anticlockwise and the other pass cull faces clockwise.

The shader does a dot product between the normal and the camera position and then modulate the transparency based on that result.

[image]

```
#version 100
precision highp int;
precision highp float;

uniform float time;
uniform float touchX;
uniform float touchY;
uniform float touchZ;
uniform float line;



varying float  lightDiffuse;

void main()
{

    float rampLight =lightDiffuse;

    float light = (1.0 - rampLight) * 1.0;
    vec4 lightColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = lightColor * light;

    vec4 c;
    if(rampLight < 0.0 )
    {
        discard;
    }
    diffuseColor = smoothstep(vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8), vec4(diffuseColor));
    gl_FragColor = diffuseColor;

}




material Router
{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {

            scene_blend alpha_blend
            depth_write on
            depth_check on
            cull_hardware anticlockwise

            vertex_program_ref movingline_101_vs 
            {

            }

            fragment_program_ref movingline_101_fs
            {

            }
        }


        pass
        {


            scene_blend alpha_blend
            cull_hardware clockwise
            depth_write on
            depth_check on

            vertex_program_ref movingline_101_vs 
            {

            }

            fragment_program_ref movingline_101_fs
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Update:

```
material Router
{
    technique
    {       
        pass
        {

            depth_write on

             vertex_program_ref pass_101_vs 
            {

            }

            fragment_program_ref pass_101_fs
            {

            }


        }

          pass
        {
            depth_write off

            depth_fun equal
            scene_blend add

            vertex_program_ref movingline_101_vs 
            {

            }

            fragment_program_ref movingline_101_fs
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

pass shader

```
void main()
{

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

}
```

main shader:

```
#version 120
precision highp int;
precision highp float;

uniform float time;
uniform float touchX;
uniform float touchY;
uniform float touchZ;
uniform float line;



    varying float  lightDiffuse;

    void main()
    {

        float rampLight =lightDiffuse;

        float light = (1.0 - rampLight) * 1.0;
        vec4 lightColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0);
        vec4 diffuseColor = lightColor * light;


        diffuseColor = smoothstep(vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9), vec4(diffuseColor));
         gl_FragColor = diffuseColor;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to render something with transparency, but without being able to see the faces which would be occluded if it was opaque, then a common simple technique is to prime the depth buffer first.

Pass 1: Write to just the depth buffer. Easiest way to achieve this is by rendering with blending on and a shader that just outputs vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for every fragment. There may be more efficient ways to prime the depth buffer (e.g. using glColorMask instead of blending), but this approach is simple and probably good enough.

Pass 2: Render with a depth test of GL_EQUAL. Use whatever shader you like.

Performance note: discard is often slower than just outputting vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for pixels you want to be transparent on mobile hardware, so avoid discard unless you really need it - in this case you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I have tried your approach but the object is black with no transparency at all

Comment: Did you have blending on for both passes?

Comment: should I disable blending in the two passes ?

Comment: Enable blending for both passes.

Comment: which blending scheme ? alpha_blend ? add or modulate ? I have no transparency at all even after enabling the blending

Comment: Using glColorMask will definitely be more efficient